# Problem using @Valid with Spring MVC application deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, validation, annotations

I am building a Spring MVC application and deploying to Tomcat.  When I try to use the @Valid syntax, I get a compilation error:

Valid cannot be resolved to a type.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Helios SR2).

I have hibernate-validator.jar in my classpath, as the Spring documentation indicates, but I don't see javax.validation.* anywhere in my references.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

to your context and you have to have javax.validation.* classes on classpath
search for javax.validation in maven repositories or use following if you use Maven:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.validation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I know the problem is that I don't have javax.validation.* in my class path. Never used Maven.  I'll have to look into it.